# why $\{a+x: x \in I \}$ is the set of congruence class of $a \in R$ with $R$ a ring and $I$ an ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I know that if we have a ring $R$ and $I$ an ideal of R, a congruence relation is

$a \equiv b (mod I)$ if $a-b\in I$

but why this set

$\{a+x: x \in I \}$ is the set of congruence class of $a $

I can see that if we take $b \in $$\{a+x: x \in I \}$ then $b= a+i$ for some $i \in I$

but if  $a\equiv b $ (mod $I$) then
$a-b=a-(a+i)=-i $ but if $-i\in I$ then $I=R$ because it contains $-i$

is not better define $\{a-x: x \in I \}$

Comment: An ideal is a group under +.  Thus $-i$ is in $I$ if $i$ is.

Comment: First, it is not "the *set of* congruence class of $a$". It *is* the class of $a.$ Secondly, if $i\in I$ then $-i\in I,$ but that does not imply $I=R.$ Both $I$ and $R$ contain $-i$, that's all. Thirdly, $\{a-x: x \in I \}$ is equal to $\{a+y:y\in I \}.$

Comment: Thank to both! i got confused -i with $i^{-1}$ i dont know why im sory